# How to overcome the Could not convert String to Float?

Tags: python-3.x, string, pandas, multiple-columns

Hi Everyone I'm Having This Two Columns:

```
Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] = Mi_Meteo['Measurement'].str.rstrip(' Measure')
Mi_Meteo['Measurement'].head()

0    0.8
1    0.6
2    0.4
3    0.4
4      0
Name: Measurement, dtype: object
```

And:

```
Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'] = Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'].str.rstrip(' ID')
Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'].head()
0    14121
1    14121
2    14121
3    14121
4    14121
Name: Sensor_ID, dtype: object
```

So , i tried to convert both of them to float , nut was got an error:

```
Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] = Mi_Meteo['Measurement'].astype(float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

And:

```
Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'] = Mi_Meteo['Sensor_ID'].astype(float)

ValueError: could not convert string to float:
```

Any Suggestion , would be much appreciated , thank U all.

Comment: Try using `pd.to_numeric` with `errors='coerce'`.  Looks like you have some bad data.  Either that or you're not stripping enough, might need to strip the final result as well

Comment: I had to tweak a bit a couple of other things , and at the end it worked , Thanks Again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible reason could be some white space in your data which didn't clear out. Add in `str.strip()` before converting to `float`.

```
Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] = Mi_Meteo['Measurement'].str.rstrip(' Measure').str.strip()
Mi_Meteo['Measurement'] = Mi_Meteo['Measurement'].astype(float)
```

Comment: Thanks for EveryThing , I addes a couple of things , but at the end it worked , Thank Again.